# Overleaf: Bibliography displaying first item on different page

Tags: bibliographies, citing, overleaf, multiple-citations

I have the following citations made in a .bib file:

```
\bibliographystyle{apa}
@article{nii1986blackboard,
  title={The blackboard model of problem solving and the evolution of blackboard architectures},
  author={Nii, H Penny},
  journal={AI magazine},
  volume={7},
  number={2},
  pages={38--38},
  year={1986}
}
@inproceedings{gallofr2021news,
  title={The news angler project: Exploring the next generation of journalistic knowledge platforms},
  author={Gallofr, Marc and Opdahl, Andreas L and Stoppel, Sergej and Tessem, Bj{\o}rnar and Veres, Csaba and others},
  booktitle={Norsk IKT-konferanse for forskning og utdanning},
  number={2},
  year={2021}
}
@article{opdahl2021ontologies,
  title={Ontologies for finding journalistic angles},
  author={Opdahl, Andreas L and Tessem, Bj{\o}rnar},
  journal={Software and Systems Modeling},
  volume={20},
  pages={71--87},
  year={2021},
  publisher={Springer}
}
@article{motta2020analysis,
  title={Analysis and design of computational news angles},
  author={Motta, Enrico and Daga, Enrico and Opdahl, Andreas L and Tessem, Bj{\o}rnar},
  journal={IEEE Access},
  volume={8},
  pages={120613--120626},
  year={2020},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
@article{berven2020knowledge,
  title={A knowledge-graph platform for newsrooms},
  author={Berven, Arne and Christensen, Ole A and Moldeklev, Sindre and Opdahl, Andreas L and Villanger, Kjetil J},
  journal={Computers in Industry},
  volume={123},
  pages={103321},
  year={2020},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{grishman2019twenty,
  title={Twenty-five years of information extraction},
  author={Grishman, Ralph},
  journal={Natural Language Engineering},
  volume={25},
  number={6},
  pages={677--692},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Cambridge University Press}
}
@article{hevner2008design,
  title={Design science in information systems research},
  author={Hevner, Alan R and March, Salvatore T and Park, Jinsoo and Ram, Sudha},
  journal={Management Information Systems Quarterly},
  volume={28},
  number={1},
  pages={6},
  year={2004}
}
@inproceedings{song2015light,
  title={From light to rich ere: annotation of entities, relations, and events},
  author={Song, Zhiyi and Bies, Ann and Strassel, Stephanie and Riese, Tom and Mott, Justin and Ellis, Joe and Wright, Jonathan and Kulick, Seth and Ryant, Neville and Ma, Xiaoyi},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the the 3rd Workshop on EVENTS: Definition, Detection, Coreference, and Representation},
  pages={89--98},
  year={2015}
}
@inproceedings{ratinov2009design,
  title={Design challenges and misconceptions in named entity recognition},
  author={Ratinov, Lev and Roth, Dan},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the thirteenth conference on computational natural language learning (CoNLL-2009)},
  pages={147--155},
  year={2009}
}
```

And in my .tex file I have them added as such:

```
\cite{nii1986blackboard}
\cite{gallofr2021news}
\cite{opdahl2021ontologies}
\cite{motta2020analysis}
\cite{berven2020knowledge}
\cite{grishman2019twenty}
\cite{hevner2008design}
\cite{song2015light}
\cite{ratinov2009design}
```

However, for some reason the first item is displayed on a seperate page before the Bibliography.
[image: First item is on a separate page before the rest]

[image: The rest of them however are fine]

How come its not displaying the first item along with the rest of them?

Comment: if you have `\bibliographystyle{apa}` in your bib file you will get errors and perhaps the output you show, hard to say as you provide no example,

Comment: @David-Carlisle I tried moving it to the .tex file, however the same issue occurs. What am I missing examples of? I've included relevant .bib file and .tex file, and images of the output depicting the issue. But if it helps, I'm using this template for my paper: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/masters-thesis-pre-template-infomedia-for-university-of-bergen/xzwdyfrytxpw

Comment: you have not provided an example that people can run to see the isssue but certainly remove that line from the bib file.

Answer (score 1):

There are no `apa.bst` in TeX Live, I think you should use `apalike`. And you should remove `\bibliographystyle{apa}` from `.bib` file.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\cite{nii1986blackboard}
\cite{gallofr2021news}
\cite{opdahl2021ontologies}
\cite{motta2020analysis}
\cite{berven2020knowledge}
\cite{grishman2019twenty}
\cite{hevner2008design}
\cite{song2015light}
\cite{ratinov2009design}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the issue, as the first citation is still not appearing under References. And while your suggested LaTeX code presents the citations better, it removes all the preceding pages from appearing, only leaving the References page (which might be due to the other pages having their own dedicated .tex file).

Comment: @Garosath You should distinguish between the differences in author year and number style.

Comment: You're right; I didn't notice that the top element is a list of authors and author years, not a citation. The references list is properly set up now, only issue is that every preceding page doesn't get shown, leaving only the References page.

Comment: What is "every preceding page"? You don't shown them.

Comment: The references are at the end of my paper. I use this template for my paper: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/masters-thesis-pre-template-infomedia-for-university-of-bergen/xzwdyfrytxpw

Comment: I am confused now, not sure what you want. Can you describe your needs more clearly?

Comment: I can't seem to add images to comments so I'll have to describe the problem:
Before implementing your changes, Overleaf would show all of my pages (Cover page, table of contents page, introduction page etc.), and the page at the bottom was my Bibliography.
However, after implementing your changes it stopped showing all the other pages, only showing me the very last page, namely the References page.

Comment: @Garosath Clara has shown a test document with only references, naturally you have to merge this back in to your real text